# Why can the dispersion relation for a linear chain of atoms (connected by springs) be written as $\omega(k)=c_s \lvert k\rvert$?

Tags: solid-state-physics, phonons, dispersion

On the [german wikipedia site](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon) (right under "Akustische Moden"), the dispersion relation for a linear chain of atoms (connected by springs):

$$\omega(k)=2 \sqrt{\frac{K}{M}} \left \vert \sin{\frac{ka}{2}}\right \vert$$

is approximated as:

$$ \omega (k)\approx c_s \lvert k\rvert$$

for small $k$. ($c_s$ is the speed of sound). Why are we allowed to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because by expanding the sinus term into a taylor expansion, you get

$\sin(x)\approx x - \frac{x^3}{6} +\cdots$

So, for small values of k you are allowed to take just the linear term.

Comment: Thanks. That would give me: $$a  \sqrt{\frac{K}{M}} \lvert k\rvert$$ though. I don't see how $a \sqrt{\frac{K}{M}}$ can be approximated as $c_s$. $a$ is the distance between two atoms in the lattice, $K$ the spring konstant and $M$ the mass.

Comment: $$c_s$$ is just the speed of sound, which connects (in your linear dispersion relation) the frequency with the momentum. So, this is just the speed of sound by definition.

Comment: To elaborate upon what qmd, QuantumMechanics said, the speed of sound is defined  either the "phase velocity" $\omega/k$, or the "group velocity", $d\omega / d k$. Whenever $\omega=Ak$ for some $A$, one may see that the group velocity and the phase velocity coincide and both are equal to $A$.

Comment: @LubošMotl Just for clarification, dispersion occurs when the group velocity differs from the phase velocity right? So, $\omega(k)=ak$ only holds if the group velocity equals the phase velocity? In my example $\omega$ and $\frac{d\omega}{d k}$ have the same velocity as far as I can see so there is no dispersion and I can write $\omega=c_sk$. The one thing I am not getting is how I can just replace $a \sqrt{\frac{K}{M}}$ with $c_s$?

Comment: Yes, $\omega=Ak$ holds if and only if the group velocity is equal to the phase velocity, and this is also equivalent to having no dispersion - i.e. no dependence of either velocity on $k$ or equivalently on $\omega$. You can replace $a\sqrt{K/M}$ by $c_s$ e.g. using the delete key several times (on a PC), or using a rubber on a pencil, and then writing $c_s$ to the place you emptied, or by writing the equation once again with $c_s$ instead of the previous form of the coefficient. The point is that they are *equal* by the definition of $c_s$ so you are allowed to do that.

Comment: The problem you are facing must be something rather basic so let me preemptively say that the sentence "they are equal" may also be written mathematically as $c_s = a\sqrt{K/M}$, and that's why you may replace one by the other, right? This identity may be derived from $c_s=\omega / k$, the definition of the phase velocity, if you substitute $\omega = a\sqrt{K/M} k$ for $\omega$. Still a problem?

Comment: @LubošMotl Thanks for the humerous explanation (I think I needed that slap in the face). ;) It makes sense now. I just didn't see how $a \sqrt{\frac{K}{M}}$ could be a velocity but the unit analysis: $$[m]\sqrt{\frac{[kg]}{[kg][s^2]}}=\frac{[m]}{[s]}$$ checks out. Also, by just looking at the definition of the dispersion relation $\omega=v_p k$ it makes total sense why $v_p=c_s$ by definition. I don't know why I couldn't see that before. Thank you Lubos and thank you QuantumMechanics!

Comment: Great outcome. The units had to be the same for the coefficient claiming to be $c_s$ or replaced with $c_s$, otherwise the original equation would have been dimensionally incorrect. The broader lesson is that there are various formulae to *calculate* the speeds. For example, the speed of light may be calculated from the elementary coefficients $\epsilon_0,\mu_0$ that appear in the static electric and magnetic force laws as $c=1/\sqrt{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}$. Many other examples where the things depend on material constants etc. exist, too.